# How to find content in large sized files

Tags: linux, files, grep

I have a large-size text file.(about 2GB)

I'll call you **A.txt**

I want to know if the **A.txt** file contains the **sentence** I want(The size of the **sentence** is 1Byte~500MB)

Also, if the **sentence** is included in **A.txt**, I would like to know the location included in byte

Comment: You seem to know `grep`, you probably know options `-b` and `-o` for GNU `grep`, so what exactly is your question?

Comment: @Philippos I know `grep` can't compare multiple lines. The search keyword I want is not a line. I want to search for a number of lines of 500MB size

Comment: Ah. Maybe better edit to say "multi-line sentence". Where is that "sentence" stored -- in a file? You probably don't want a 500 MB pattern in your command line (-;

Comment: @Philippos Actually, that's a problem. I am worried about making a 500 MB size pattern into a file without putting it in the command line. And that would eventually compare files to files.

Comment: perhaps a better solution would be by using perl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $re=shift;
$re =~ s/[[:blank:]]+/\\s+/g;#/this comment only exists to fix SEs perl highlighting

my $blocksize = 100000;
my $filesize;

foreach my $file (@ARGV) {
  open(F,"<",$file) || die "couldn't open '$file': $!\n";

  $filesize=(stat($file))[7];

  my @matches=();
  for (my $i = 0; $i <= $filesize; $i+=$blocksize-(length($re))) {
    seek(F,$i,0);
    read F,$_,$blocksize;
    @matches=(m/$re/gmo);
    print join("\n",@matches), "\n" if (@matches);
    };
  close(F);
};
```

Save this as,e.g., `puregyu.pl`, make it executable with `chmod +x puregyu.pl` and run it as:

```perl
./puregyu.pl 'my sentence' a.txt
```

This script takes the first argument (the search string or pattern) and changes any blank spaces (`[[:blank:]]`, i.e. spaces and tabs) to `\s*` (any whitespace, including spaces, tabs, linefeeds and formfeeds) to allow sentences to match even if they cross lines.   See `man perlrecharclass` for details on how whitespace is defined.

Any remaining arguments are treated as filenames to search.

In order to avoid loading the entire input file into memory at once, this script scans a "block" of input at a time.   To avoid missing any input, it increments the offset variable (`$i`) used by the `read` statement by `($blocksize - length($re)` instead of just `$blocksize`).

I've set the blocksize to 1000000, so it will read 100KiB at a time - I don't have a suitable large text file to test with, so you might have to tweak this for optimal performance.

NOTE: Getting the byte location of the matches is more work than I have time for right now.  Perhaps someone else could help with that.

---

To match an enormous multi-line "sentence", the following would work better.  It allows you to specify a filename instead of a string as the first argument.  then it slurps in that entire file and turns it into a regular expression.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

use File::Slurp;

my $re = read_file(shift,chomp=>1);
$re=~s/[[:blank:]]+/\\s+/gm;#/this comment only exists to fix SEs perl highlighting

my $blocksize = length($re)*5;
my $filesize;

foreach my $file (@ARGV) {
  open(F,"<",$file) || die "couldn't open '$file': $!\n";

  $filesize=(stat($file))[7];

  my @matches=();
  for (my $i = 0; $i <= $filesize; $i+=$blocksize-(length($re))) {
    seek(F,$i,0);
    read F,$_,$blocksize;
    @matches=(m/$re/gmo);
    print join("\n",@matches), "\n" if (@matches);
    };
  close(F);
};
```

Save this as,e.g., `puregyu2.pl`, make it executable with `chmod +x puregyu2.pl` and run it as:

```perl
./puregyu2.pl searchfile.txt a.txt
```

---

Finally, neither of these scripts are fully-tested.  I don't have either an enormous text file to search or an enormous "sentence" to search for.   Accordingly, these are offered as approximate pointers in one possible right direction rather than as complete, working code.